# Cursor keys not working when using sqlite3 from adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite, adb, readline

When using sqlite3 through `adb shell` arrow keys, instead of moving the cursor to the desired position or summoning the history facility, the following is showed in the screen: `^[[A`, `^[[B`, `^[[C`, `^[[D`.

I'm using Mac OS X and I have tried **Terminal** and **iTerm** terminal emulators.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The same situation is with Linux. In Windows arrows keys work correctly.

Comment: Would something like [rlwrap](http://freecode.com/projects/rlwrap) solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow editing and history in the input of a console program, that program must be linked with the `readline` library.

The `sqlite3` tool does support readline, but on Android, readline support has been disabled.
(Probably because readline is licensed only under the GPL.)

Comment: Actually, when I launch `adb shell` the command history seems to work, at least partially, because I can move to previously executed commands. Besides the problem with the `readline` library, the main point here is that the application is not mapping correctly the arrows keys, because it doesn't recognize even the left and right keys. Any idea about this?

Comment: `adb` runs partially on the host. The cursor keys would be handled by `readline`.

Comment: Thanks @CL.. Good to know. So probably there is no easy way to make line editing and history capabilities work. However, if somebody has found a solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround would be to use a local version of SQLite with readline support.

1. Copy a database file from your device to your local machine:
   `adb pull <database-file-on-device>`
2. Use your local version of SQLite to access the database file:
   `sqlite3 <database-file-on-local>`
3. If you made changes you can transfer them to the device. Copy your local database file from your local machine to your device:
   `sqlite3 <database-file-on-local> <database-file-on-device>`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the previous command functionality in the adb shell. So just adb shell. Then cd to the /data/data//databases directory. From here run (for example): sqlite3  "select * from "

Then you can use up arrow to redo that command. Kind of a hack, but way better than having to retype the command inside the sqlite3 interactive prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Khanad's answer: I wrote a shell script on the device and I send my sqlite commands through it.

First create a script file on the device and make it executable:

```
# get on the device
$ adb shell 

# get write access on the device (this will also put you in the data/data directory)
$ run-as com.YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_APP_NAME

# create the script file
$ touch qlite

# make it executable
$ chmod +x qlite
```

Then add this code to the script. Remember to put your actual app name in there. (The echoes just add a little breathing room to the output.)

```
echo

sqlite3 databases/YOUR_APP_NAME -cmd ".mode column" ".headers on" "$1;"

echo
```

Then you just have to do something like:

```
./qlite "select * from table limit 1"
```

The script will pass the sqlite command through, tack on the semi-colon, pretty print it with column names and you can use the up arrow to get your last command. And because you have write access you can make updates directly to the DB on the device.

I hope this makes someone's life easier!

Answer (score 0):

Use ADB shell instead of sqlite3 shell to get the advantage of the readline package.

```
generic_x86:/data/data/com.example.musicplayer/databases $ sqlite3 music_player_database -line 'select * from lastplayedsong;'
```

Just make sure you are in the correct package and don't put **.db** at the end of the database name otherwise a new database would be created and the query would return you no result.
*P.S: [source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3)*

Comment: - "Just make sure you are in the correct package and don't put .db at the end of the database name otherwise a new database would be created and the query would return you no result." - It actually works the other way round. If you do not add a **.db** a new database will be created