# Android SQLite3 with history commands

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I'm using Genymotion for my project.
If I using sqlite3 I can't navigate into my history commands.

(Look into [Cursor keys not working when using sqlite3 from adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747564/cursor-keys-not-working-when-using-sqlite3-from-adb-shell) this thread).

I need to observe my database in a frequently way, and all time I have to digit CTRL+C, CTRL-V on latest query.

Are there workarounds? Is it possible that android doesn't allow to check the database history commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging SQL queries in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966584/logging-sql-queries-in-android)